# Count number of times a string of text appears on a page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, count, cpu-word, onload

I have a view in an MVC web application that produces and presents a list of countries and the name of their capital cities. Whenever the view loads, if the results presented to the user contain the words 'Australia' one or more times, then I want a message to appear at the bottom of the screen that says 'Australia is included in the results'. I have used the following script, but the message appears whether or not Australia is in the results. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        if (
          (
            document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText
         ).indexOf('Australia') > -1
        ) {
            alert("Australia is included in the results");
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: put the text into a variable and see what it contains with a debugger. `var text = document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks sensible, so I suspect that the problem is that it is finding the string "Australia" *in the code its self*!

Try putting this script outside of the page contents (in a separate .js file) and see if the problem persists.

Maybe ;-)

Comment: I think you're right. I am using this script on a partial view. Do you know if document.documentElement.textContent includes all of the original views that direct to this partial view? The only way I can get the alert to disappear using my original code is to set (-1) to (1000). I have no idea why this works.

Comment: Funny bug! `document.documentElement.textContent` will fetch whatever is in the document at the time you call it, including scripts tags and their contents in the page. Try moving your script out of the page (into a javascript file).

Comment: You seem to know a fair bit about this, so I thought I would ask one more question - is it possible to simple replace the 'alert' with a <div> string.Format("Australia is included in the results </div> and have it display at the bottom on the screen in the results?

Answer (score 1):

I think only this condition might suffice:

```
if (document.documentElement.innerText.indexOf('Australia') > -1) {
    alert("Australia is included in the results");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3gkzC/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an answer for your follow up question about using HTML instead of an alert (I can't post comments, so had to do it this way, sorry.)

What you want is `document.getElementById("element_ID").innerHTML = "whatever";`

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/UVU8w/